# Flutter separate folder for images in Android and iOS

Tags: dart, flutter

There are 20 images in my project 10 is for Android and 10 for iOS, currently I am having a folder in project level named `assets` and I have added all my images there. So, will the other 10 images count in size when the app is built for only Android and vice versa.

Or should I put my files somewhere else so that iOS images are not counted for Android and vice versa to keep apk size minimum.

Comment: assets/android/yourimages , assets/ios/yourimages, then in your code use the path name according to the platform (android/ios)

Comment: @diegoveloper but when the app is built, won't the other platform counted in size? Because eventually all the images stay in assets folder.

Comment: yea, that's is an issue that is being discussed : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23122